# What is an isomorphic graph (geometrical interpretation)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I've seen definitions stating that

"If $G=(V,E)$ and $G'=(V',E')$ , then a mapping $\theta : V \rightarrow V'$ is an isomorphism if, for all $u,v \in V$,

$uv \in E$ if and only if $\theta (u) \theta (v) \in E'$. "

This definition makes little (applicable) sense to me. Geometrically speaking, what is an isometric tree, and how is it different to a non-isomorphic tree?

Answer (score 1):

In loose terms, two graphs $G$ and $H$ are said to be *isomorphic* if there is a way to "draw" the graph $G$ to look like $H$.

For example, consider the claw graph $K_{1,3}$ and the path $P_4$ with 3 edges. These graphs are both trees, but they are said to be non-*isomorphic* because there is no way to move around the vertices and edges of $K_{1,3}$ to obtain the path $P_4$.

In general for larger graphs, it is very difficult to determine if two graphs are isomorphic.

Consider the two graphs pictured below.

[image: petersengraph]

While these graphs look very different at first glance, they are actually isomorphic! This can be seen by the labeling of the vertices: if we move all of the vertices of one graph to have the same positions as pictured in the other graph, we will actually be looking at the same graph! (The are two different drawings of the *Petersen Graph*)

Comment: But aren't those 2 graphs identical? I mean, they both contain the exact same edges and vertices. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that example can be misleading with the labeling. Think of the second graph as having vertices with labels $0', 1', \dots, 9'$ to emphasize that these are in fact two *different* vertex sets.